# BroadcastReceiver и Action.View

Tags: android, android-intent

Здравствуйте!

У меня стала задача сделать фильтр неявного интента (android.intent.action.VIEW).

Главная задача состоит в том, что бы когда пользователь переходит по ссылкам в других приложениях или в браузере и открывает определенный тип ссылок с нужными данными, я обрабатываю это в своем приложении.

Была попытка сделать с помощью  просто в активности, но из за неполной реализации в манифесте pathPattern(не полный regExp) фильтр сделать нельзя.

Вопрос стал на обработке событий в системе с помощью BroadcastReceiver и только при нужной нам ссылке отправлять в приложение.(даже когда приложение не запущено).

```
<receiver
            android:name=".ExampleReveiver"
            android:enabled="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW" />
                </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

И таким классом ресивера:

```
public class ExampleReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
            String url = intent.getDataString();
            if (url != null) {
                if (pattern.matcher(url).matches())
                    try {
                        long id = URLUtils.getIdFromUrl(url);
                        Intent app_intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        app_intent.putExtra("id", id);
                        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    }
            } else {
                register_receiver(context, false);
                Intent redirectIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intent.getData());
                context.startActivity(redirectIntent);
                register_receiver(context, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void register_receiver(Context ctx, boolean register) {
        PackageManager packageManager = ctx.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName receiverName = new ComponentName(ctx, ExampleReceiver.class);
        if (register) {
            packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiverName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        } else {
            packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiverName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        }
    }
```

И данный код должен работать, когда приходят в систему Intent с Action.View.  Но ресивер просто не работает. И не обрабатывает сообщения.

Comment: По идее вам всё же нужно в интент-фильтер добавить и схемы с путями. Хотя бы самые общие типа http. Так у вас должен будет вызываться ресивер на любую ссылку

Comment: <data
                        android:pathPattern=".*"
                        android:pathPrefix="/"
                        android:scheme="http" />
Ничего не дал. Реакции 0.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё вот это в фильтр добавить: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />`

Comment: Я не знаю, работает ли Broadcastreceiver с данным типом сообщений(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW).

Comment: На этот счёт я и сам не уверен, но ссылки отлавливаются. Попробуйте только ссылки отлавливать

Comment: Возможно у вас есть пример с отловом ссылок?

Comment: Посмотрите тут манифест и соответствующую активити https://github.com/mohaxspb/Odnako

Comment: Если у вас получилось, то вы можете сами написать ответ и получить ачивку и репутацию)